# VueJS event callback spy doesn't work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, karma-runner

I have a VueJS component `text-editor` that I call as such in my tests:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import TextEditor from '../src/TextEditor.vue';
import expect, {spyOn} from 'expect';

describe("<text-editor>", (done) => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        this.vm = new Vue({
            data: { hi: { text: "hi" } },
            template: '<div><text-editor ref="texteditor" v-model="hi" @hide="hidecb"></text-editor></div>',
            components: { 'text-editor': TextEditor },
            methods: {
                hidecb: function() {
                    console.log('hide');
                }
            }
        }).$mount();
    });

    it("should call the @hide callback", (done) => {
        let spy = spyOn(this.vm, 'hidecb');

        // This call will trigger an this.$emit('hide') in the component
        this.vm.$refs.texteditor.save();

        Vue.nextTick(() => {
            expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Weird thing is, method `hidecb` does get called and I see "hide" on the console. But the spy will fail with the following error:

```
Error: spy was not called (undefined:29)
```

I checked and the callback is indeed called before nextTick. I should also point out that I am using Webpack, expectjs and karma.

Would someone be able to point out why the spy doesn't work?